# Kakfa Partition in Docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, partition

I have Kubernetes ckuster created with kafka pods.
I am using docker image confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.2 for this.

I want to add more partition to it.
Can you let me know if there is a config or env in confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.2 to change the partition size

Answer (score 0):

User topic-partition counts are not a docker environment variable

You can increase partitions using `kafka-topics` command

[Kafka topic partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49054946/kafka-topic-partitions)